# How to delete specific table data from a table?

Tags: watir-webdriver

In my application I've a table with 40 rows. How do I delete some specific `<td>` named as "default", "tags", "city", "organic" in that table? All the deletes links are images with the same src name. Please find the attachment of the table row.

My step def:

```
Then(/^I click on all the delete rules on the setup page$/) do
  words = ["default", "tags","organic","city"]
  @current_page.delete_rules(:words => words)
end
```

In my ruby class I've added delete_rules method as below:

```
def delete_rules(words)
  image_elements(:src => "/tracker/images/skin2/bin.png").click
end
```

Problem here is its deleting the first row in the table, not the rows which I've mentioned in the array.

My HTML is:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="edit.page?id=83">tags</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="delete.page?did=83">
            <img title="Delete" src="/tracker/images/skin2/bin.png">
        </a>
        <a href="edit.page?id=83">
        <a href="activate.page?id=83">
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
```

Comment: <tr><td><a href="edit.page?id=83">tags</a></td><td><a href="delete.page?did=83">
<img title="Delete" src="/tracker/images/skin2/bin.png">
</a>
<a href="edit.page?id=83">
<a href="activate.page?id=83">
</td>
<td> </td>

Comment: What is `image_elements` in the `delete_rules`? This looks similar to the page object gem, but that method would have thrown an exception due to the array not having a the `click` method defined (unless your actual code is `image_element` - ie no 's').

Answer (score 0):

you should use the following code in your delete method:

```
#check all <tr>
@browser.trs.each do  |row|
   # the row below will check the first <td> text in order to find "default", "tags", "city","organic" 
    if row.text.match(/default|tags|organic|city/)!= nil
      # the row below will click the 1st link in the 2nd <td> 
      row.td(:index=>1).link.click
    end
end
```